# Python 3 is behaving like Python 2 division gives no remainder and print isn't a function

Tags: visual-studio, printing, python-3.7

I am new to python I just did a fresh install for python 3.7.4 64-bit (it displays this on the bottom of VS). I am coding and using the built in terminal in Visual Studio and have installed the python plug in.  Running some simple programs and they seem to behave like I am using Python 2 instead of 3.  print() isn't a function and division creates an integer. Please help

```
xh = input("Enter Hours:")
xr = input("Enter Rate:")
xp = float(xr) * float(xh)
print ('Pay:', xp)

print(9/2)
```

Output:
('Pay:', 7490.0)
4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your environmental variables. I think it is pointing to python2.

Comment: Python 3 was located somewhere other than c: which the installed picked changed the path environmental variable to properly find it and now it works perfectly thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try the same code in `cmd.exe` check the results. If you are getting same results then check your environmental variables.

Comment: Just tried cmd.exe and problem persists.  Though when I did this I noticed that when start python it shows this: Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  Not sure why it's loading 2.7 when I have 3 installed